# Insert row every nth value from one dataframe to another in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to insert many rows from one dataframe to another. I managed to do it once, but I have to do the same 3500 times.

I have the following two dataframes with the same headers:

dataframe a with 850561 rows and 121 columns

dataframe b with 854001 rows and 121 columns

And I used the following code to insert a row from b to a:

```
a <- rbind(a[1:244,],b[245],a[-(1:244),])
```

This works perfectly because it inserts a row from b in between rows 244 and 245 of a.

The problem is that I have to do the same every 243 rows, for example the next would be something like this:

```
a <- rbind(a[246:489,],b[489],a[-(246:489),])
```

I have tried with the following for loop, but it does not work:

```
i<-244
j<-1
for (val in a){
  a<-rbind(a[j:i,],b[i+1],a[-(j:i),])
  i<-i+243
  j<j+245
}
```

I would much appreciate your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible approach is to `rbind(a,b)` into a single table, with a new variable which when sorted on gives rows in the correct order.

This new variable would take the values `1:(dim(a)[1])` for the existing rows of a, then 245.5, 489.5, etc for the rows of `b`.  Then if I sort on it the rows of `b` will appear in the correct place.

(Edit: I've just realised this is slightly different to your situation, but it should be easily adaptable, all you would need to do is select the appropriate rows of `b` first)

Here's a toy example:

```
# Create a and b
a <- data.frame(x=runif(15),source="a")
b <- data.frame(x=runif(3),source="b")

# Suppose I want b interleaved with a, such that a row of b occurs every 5 rows of a:

a$sortorder <- 1:dim(a)[1]
b$sortorder <- (1:dim(b)[1])*5+0.5

dat <- rbind(a,b)
dat[order(dat$sortorder),-3]

            x source
1  0.10753897      a
2  0.24482683      a
3  0.72236241      a
4  0.03273494      a
5  0.54934999      a
16 0.20578103      b
6  0.68280868      a
7  0.30024090      a
8  0.38877446      a
9  0.73244615      a
10 0.96249642      a
17 0.13878037      b
11 0.76059617      a
12 0.58167316      a
13 0.46287299      a
14 0.35630962      a
15 0.38392182      a
18 0.38908214      b
```

Comment: This solution is very creative and looks great, however, when I implemented it, it did not work. When I tried multiplying by 243 instead of 5, the sorting does not work. The rows added appears in incremental of 1. For example, the first one worked fine and it appeared in the row 244 as desired, but the next one appeared in the row 490 instead of 489, and so on so forth.

Comment: you probably need to multiply by 242 then, and possibly make some offset.  in my example i had a row of b appearing for every 5 rows of a, which means that every sixth row of the final dataset will be a row of b.

Comment: Hi, yes you are right, I have voted the answer as accepted now. Thanks George